# R: error creating a termDocumentMatrix() object

Tags: r, term-document-matrix

Here's my code that I used to create the termdocumentmatrix object for training data:

```
text_train = iconv(data_train$SentimentText, "UTF-8", "ASCII", sub = "")
corpus_train = Corpus(VectorSource(text_train))
tdm_train = TermDocumentMatrix(
  corpus_train,
  control = list(
    removePunctuation = TRUE,
    removestopWords   = TRUE,
    stemming = FALSE,
    removeNumbers = TRUE, 
    tolower = TRUE,
    weighting = weightTfIdf)
)
```

and it works! no complains from the machines.

HOWEVER, when I use the SAME technique to create one for validation data set, the machine complains!

here's my code I used to create the termdocumentmatrix object for validaiton set. notice the ONLY difference is that I added the "dictionary" argument to the control:

```
text_val = iconv(data_val$SentimentText, "UTF-8", "ASCII", sub = "")
corpus_val = Corpus(VectorSource(text_val))
tdm_val = TermDocumentMatrix(
  corpus_val,
  control = list(
    removePunctuation = TRUE,
    removestopWords   = TRUE,
    stemming = FALSE,
    removeNumbers = TRUE, 
    tolower = TRUE,
    weighting = weightTfIdf,
    dictionary = tdm_train$dimnames$Terms
  )
)
```

however, I keep getting the following error message:

> Error in simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v), nrow =
>   length(allTerms),  :    'i, j, v' different lengths

I've read through many posts, including:

1. [DocumentTermMatrix fails with a strange error only when # terms > 3000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356833/documenttermmatrix-fails-with-a-strange-error-only-when-terms-3000)
2. [Twitter Data Analysis - Error in Term Document Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504559/twitter-data-analysis-error-in-term-document-matrix)
3. [twitter data <- error in termdocumentmatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722202/twitter-data-error-in-termdocumentmatrix)
4. [Twitter Data Analysis - Error in Term Document Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504559/twitter-data-analysis-error-in-term-document-matrix)

and I tried ALL of their suggested solutions, but none works.

one note I'd like to add is that the problem only occurs when I use more than about 2000 tweets.

**note about the input data**:

input data is a data table with two columns, one of which is named "SentimentText" (that you see in my code above).

in this column, each row is one tweet, and each tweet is a text string, aka character().

a sample tweet, aka a row data, look like this:
"i had such a wonderful day today! :>"

any help is much much appreciated!

Comment: You'd have a look at here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790353/dictionary-is-not-supported-anymore-in-tm-package-how-to-emend-code

Best

Comment: Hi @adrian1121 thank you for the link! but the "dictionary" mentioned in the answers are not the same dictionary that im talking about here...

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide some data to reproduce the error.

Comment: @lukeA I don't think I can provide you a sample data unless I provide you with the 3-5k tweets in a csv format. would you want that? :) because like I mentioned, this problem does not happen with small data set...